# ¿Porque me da este error usando ascii_lowercase?

Tags: python, string

Soy algo nuevo en python. Intento hacer una funcion que devuelva una lista con el alfabeto, el problema es que me da el error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ascii_lowercase'y no tengo idea de porqué.

```
import string  # importamos para usar el alfabeto
    
def listAlphabet():
# devuelve una lista con el alfabeto en minusculas
return list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: De casualidad en tu programa creaste una variable llamada string además de importar el módulo?

Comment: El código publicado funciona correctamente, devolviendo el alfabeto en minúsculas.

Comment: Gracias, al final era una variable con el nombre 'string'

Answer (score 0):

Hola este problema puede pasar solo si estas nombrando el archivo que estas ejecutando string.py o tienes otro archivo en el directorio del programa que se llama asi.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

El codigo tendria que ir sin problemas

```
import string  # importamos para usar el alfabeto

def listAlphabet():
# devuelve una lista con el alfabeto en minusculas
    return list(string.ascii_lowercase)

print(listAlphabet())
```

Simplemente cambia el nombre del archivo que se llama string.py  y te funcionara.